# Replacing modal content with ajax using Colorbox

Tags: jquery, ajax, modal-dialog, colorbox

I have a series of buttons that each launch a lightbox, which is powered by 'colorbox'. Inside of each lightbox is a slider, which is powered by'RoyalSlider'. All of the sliders are in external html documents and colorbox is loading them via ajax every time a modal is triggered. You can see this working here: http://j2designpartnership.com/ob3

Unfortunitely colorbox does not have a method for switching between modal boxes (if it is pulling content via ajax). I am trying to come up with a solution that allows me to switch content within each modal from links within the modal. Currently, on the onComplete callback (when the modal finished loading), I am trying to pull new data into the slide via AJAX.

My js is as follows:

```
$('a[rel="group"]').on('click', function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    $.colorbox({

        href: $(this).attr('href'),
        //other arguments
        onComplete: function(e) {

            $('#cboxLoadedContent').find('.royalSlider').royalSlider({
             //all of the arguments here
            }).data('royalSlider');

             $('a.nextSlide').on('click', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();

                var url = $(this).attr('href'); 

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: url,
                    dataType: 'html',
                    cache: true,
                    beforeSend: function() {
                        $('#cboxLoadedContent').empty();
                        $('#cboxLoadingGraphic').show();
                    },
                    complete: function() {
                        $('#cboxLoadingGraphic').hide();
                    },
                    success: function(data) {                  
                        $('#cboxLoadedContent').append(data);
                        $('#cboxLoadedContent').find('.royalSlider').royalSlider({same arguments as above}).data('royalSlider');
                    }
                });

            });
        }
    });
});
```

Inside each modal there is a anchor link like so:

Next Slide

When clicked, it does load the new content into the modal, but on any clicks AFTER that point, it does right to the href, or the html page. This is because the first modal is running the callback, and looking for a click event...but after that it is not looking for a click event because there is no callback on the ajax call. Any ideas?

Comment: yes, that would work. I would also like a previous slide as well.

Comment: edit: next Slide should close the current one and triggers a click with .trigger() on the next Slide - it should be possible by using some kind of iteration- this may work also for previous

Comment: It would be way more elegant to replace content versus closing and opening.

Comment: yeah.. thats the chalenge ;)

Comment: Does calling your royalSlider initialisation code again just after the append not help?

Comment: Yes, it did. See update above. I just need help rerunning it over and over again

Comment: Are you also destroying the a.nextSlide between reloading? Because that could be destroying the click binding along with it. If you moved the "next click" handling higher up the DOM (using $.on('click', 'a.nextSlide', function () {blah} ), would that help?

Comment: I am not destroying the a.nextSlide anywhere...I tried moving the "next click" handeling up higher, but it only seems to work inside the onComplete colorbox callback...

Comment: UPDATE: It does work up higher in the dom if I replace "on" with "live"!